# Is any $R$-module generated by $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ be an arbitrary $R$-module, is there an epimorphism $R^{\oplus I}\to M$ in $\operatorname{Mod}R$ for some set $I$? Or when does this statement hold?

Thank you : )

Comment: When you write $R^I$, do you really mean that as a direct product, or do you actually have $R^{\oplus I}$ in mind? The latter is a free module, while the former may not be if $I$ is infinite.

Comment: This is typical by taking $I = \{m \in M\}$ and $R^{\oplus I} \twoheadrightarrow M$.

Comment: @CaptainLama direct sum $R^{\oplus I}$.

Comment: @Ryze When such clarifications happen, you should immediately make edits to your question to include the clarification. In this case I've taken the liberty to make the edit in case you're not familiar with how it works.  You can view what changes were made by clicking the timestamp on the edit indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title is misleading: the question is not whether $M$ is generated "by $R$" (that does not really mean anything), but whether it is generated by some subset. Which it is.

An $R$-module morphism $R^{\oplus I}\to M$ is entirely characterized by a function $I\to M$ (simply as sets). This is the universal property of the free module $R^{\oplus I}$. And the morphism is surjective if and only if the image of $I$ is a generating subset of $M$ as an $R$-module. So of course it is possible to find such an $I$, just take for instance $I=M$ and the identity function $I=M\to M$, since $M$ is tautologically a generating subset of itself.

Comment: *the question is not whether  is generated "by " (that does not really mean anything),* I don't agree with this.  Module theorists have a notion of what it means for "a class of modules $\mathcal U$ to generate a module $M$," (for example, Anderson and Fuller's book 106-107) and when $\mathcal U$ is a singleton $\mathcal U=\{U\}$ it is usually said that $U$ generates $M$ instead of $\mathcal U$.  In that sense, $R$ generates each of its modules.